# App not showing on computer yet the store says it's installed?

Tags: windows-8

The store tile said I had one app to update, the music app. The download seemed to be stuck so I tried to cancel to download later. Now the music app doesn't show up on my menu or when I search for it. I can't download it because the store thinks it's installed.

How can i find the app or perhaps force a new download of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you right click or swipe down from the top of the store page, you should be offered a menu item of "Your Apps".

Clicking on that will open a new page detailing, by default a list of "Apps not installed on this PC".

If the app doesn't show in that list, select "All Apps" or "Apps installed on *[ComputerName]*", right click or swipe down on the missing app, and in the task bar, select "Install".